# Django forum model with not unique posts id

Tags: django, forum

I learning python and django and trying to make some sort of simple forum. I created models:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)

class Post(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    ...
```

I'd like to have post numeration starting from 0 for every board. How i should change my models to achieve that? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're talking about using the primary key as the post ID, but that won't work if you want it to start with 0 for each board. I'd recommend adding another field on your `Post` model and manage it yourself on the `save` method. Example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    post_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.post_count = self.board.post_set.count()
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Edit:** As Brian points out, there could be problems when posts are deleted. This would result in duplicate `post_id`s. You could add a `deleted` field to the model to "fake" delete posts (don't show when `deleted` = True) which would keep the `post_id` counting accurate.

**Edit 2:** You could set the `post_count` to be equal to the maximum post count for this board + 1 (or 0 if the count is 0)

Comment: +1 on edit 2. `try: id = self.board.post_set.latest('post_count') except self.DoesNotExist: id 0`

Comment: Thank you for answer, really helpful. If i understand you right, if i will work only with 'post_count' and don't touch id itself there shouldn't be poblems with deletion?

Comment: You should use `id` for internal uses since it will be unique across all boards, but sounds like you want to use `post_count` to show users, or to have in the URL.

Comment: this introduces a race condition. (second post fetches `post_set.count()` before first posts calls `super(.., save)`). think you could fix by adding a `unique_together` on `(board, post_count)` and catching the exception (be careful not to catch other errors) on `super(.., save)` and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

If that is truly what you want, you'll have to manage it yourself by adding some kind of `IntegerField` to your `Post` model.

I'd seriously question why you would want to do that though. It will be difficult to maintain, especially if you start adding the ability to delete posts or move posts from one `Board` to another.

Comment: I think i saw that feature on kusaba imageboard, where post have id unique only to board it related, just wondering, how do one make such thing on django. Thanks for answer.